¿Como puedo hacer un metodo en donde sepa que objeto me devulve un valor?
¡Hola chic@s!
¿Como puedo hacer un metodo en donde sepa que objeto(datosMail48hs, datosMail76hs, datosMail96hs) me devolvio algun valor, llenar el objeto parametrosMail y salir?
Me ayudan porfa

Intente con un if concatenado preguntando por 48hs, 76hs y 96hs, pero repito el mismo codigo en ambos if y se hace codigo redundante

No pongas fotos, pon el código como texto.

Agrega un poco más de contexto de lo que quieres hacer y agrega el código fuente de la imagen mostrada.

Puedes crear un método que verifique cuál de los objetos (datosMail48hs, datosMail76hs, datosMail96hs) no es null y que llene el objeto parametrosMail basado en ese objeto. Luego, puedes salir del método una vez que hayas llenado parametrosMail. Mas o menos así.
private void ProcesarDatosMail()
{
// Llenar el objeto parametrosMail basado en el primer objeto que no sea 
null
if (datosMail48hs != null && datosMail48hs.ClienteId != null)
{
    LlenarParametrosMail(datosMail48hs);
    return; // Salir del método
}

if (datosMail76hs != null && datosMail76hs.ClienteId != null)
{
    LlenarParametrosMail(datosMail76hs);
    return; // Salir del método
}

if (datosMail96hs != null && datosMail96hs.ClienteId != null)
{
    LlenarParametrosMail(datosMail96hs);
    return; // Salir del método
 }
}

 private void LlenarParametrosMail(MailRequest datosMail)
{
clienteEncontrado = true;
parametrosMail.NombreCliente = dtCliente.Rows[0]["NOMBRE"].ToString() + " 
" + dtCliente.Rows[0]["APELLIDO"].ToString();
parametrosMail.ClientId = dtCliente.Rows[0]["DOMICILIO"].ToString();
}

